# Как правильно организовать синтаксис LEFT JOIN при объединении нескольких таблиц

Tags: sql, postgresql

Создайте представление (VIEW), которое будет объединять в себе все значения атрибутов по всем
поставкам. Это представление должно включать в себя в денормализованной форме все данные по
поставке из БД. Одна строка – одна поставка. Идентификаторы записей из таблиц, при помощи которых
связываем таблицы соединениями (JOIN) в представление включать НЕ НАДО. Только фактические
значения.

Таблица 1**city - справочник городов**

city_id Уникальный идентификатор города, первичный
ключ

city_name Название города

state Штат, к которому относится город

population Население города

area Площадь города

Таблица 2 **driver - справочник водителей**

driver_id Уникальный идентификатор водителя, первичный ключ

first_name Имя водителя

last_name Фамилия водителя

address Адрес водителя

zip_code Почтовый индекс водителя

phone Телефон водителя

city_id Идентификатор города водителя, внешний ключ к
таблице city

Таблица 3 **customer - справочник клиентов**

cust_id Уникальный идентификатор клиента, первичный ключ

cust_name Название клиента

annual_revenue Ежегодная выручка

cust_type Тип пользователя

address Адрес

zip Почтовый индекс

phone Телефон

city_id Идентификатор города, внешний ключ к таблице city

Таблица 4 **truck - информация о грузовиках, на которых совершаются перевозки**

truck_id Уникальный идентификатор грузовика, первичный ключ

make Производитель грузовика

model_year Дата выпуска грузовика

Таблица 5 **shipment - доставки**

ship_id  integer  Уникальный идентификатор доставки, первичный ключ

cust_id  integer  Идентификатор клиента, которому отправлена доставка, внешний ключ к таблице customer

weight  numeric  Вес посылки

truck_id  integer  Идентификатор грузовика,на котором отправлена доставка, внешний ключ к таблице truck

driver_id  integer  Идентификатор водителя, который осуществлял доставку, внешний ключ к таблице driver

city_id  integer  Идентификатор города в который совершена доставка, внешний ключ к таблице city

ship_date  date  Дата доставки

ниже пример моей организации кода. только начинаю изучать и не понимаю до конца, как правильно расположить всё. Что располагать в ON?
На просторах интернета синтаксис только для двух таблиц нашла. или нужно еще подзапрос реализовывать?

```
create view aggregate5 AS select city_name, state,population, area, weight, ship_date, first_name, last_name, sql_driver.address as address_drive, zip_code, sql_driver.phone as phone_drive, make, model_year, cust_name, annual_revenue, cust_type,  sql_customer.address as address_cust, zip, sql_customer.phone as phone_cust 
    from sql_shipment, sql_customer, sql_city, sql_driver, sql_truck 
    LEFT JOIN sql_shipment ON sql_shipment.ship_id=sql_customer.cust_id
    LEFT JOIN sql_customer on sql_customer.city_id=sql_city.city_id
    LEFT JOIN sql_city on sql_city.city_id=sql_customer.city_id
    LEFT JOIN sql_driver on sql_driver.driver_id= sql_shipment.driver_id
    LEFT JOIN sql_truck on sql_truck.truck_id=sql_shipment.truck_id
    where sql_shipment.cust_id=sql_customer.cust_id and sql_customer.city_id=sql_city.city_id and sql_shipment.driver_id=sql_driver.driver_id
```

Comment: `from A join B ON (b.a_id = a.id) join c ON (c.b_id = b.id)`  во from указывается основная таблица, затем к ней присоединяются другие. в ON надо писать соответствующее условие соединения.

Comment: @teran Вы указали в примере `join` к `join`у - `join c ON (c.b_id = b.id)`, поэтому не совсем подходит фраза *затем к ней присоединяются другие*

Comment: *На просторах интернета синтаксис только для двух таблиц нашла.* И что, там тоже каждая таблица два раза указывается - после FROM и после JOIN?

Comment: *Это представление должно включать в себя в денормализованной форме все данные по поставке из БД.* ?? Точно ВСЕ? вот точно в сведениях о поставке, пусть и денормализованной, нужно выводить, например, население города, в котором живёт доставивший поставку водитель?

Comment: Почему здесь обсуждают VIEW, когда коллега спросил про множественный LEFT JOIN?